# Blade engine works local but not on the live server

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

My laravel 5.5 project works fantastic on wamp local server and doesn't have problem with BLADE templating.

but when I serve it on live server the BLADE template doesn't work properly and debug mode shows :

```
{
"message": "Undefined variable: user (View: /home/cafegamesepanta/laravel/resources/views/child.blade.php)",
"exception": "ErrorException",
"file": "/home/cafegamesepanta/laravel/storage/framework/views/4e1f0e4c5be0294bbdada500a5c395626107f4d8.php",
"line": 2,
"trace": [

//
```

notice that I just changed permissions of /strorage folder!

anyone can help? thanks

Comment: clear your views and check again. check if $user exits

Comment: did you try to clear cache and views on server?

Comment: @Bugfixer i clear that but again my browser shows for($i=0 ; $i<10 ; $i++) ali endfor

Comment: @skileton yeah i think there is a problem with "@" mark.when i load the page it shows -> for($i=0 ; $i<10 ; $i++) ali endfor

Comment: use @ before for and endfor

Comment: did you try to dump `$user` in your blade? please show us your controller and blade files

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear all files in laravel/storage/framework/views.
2. Check that your controller has passed the User variable to views.
3. Check your database connection.